# Finding point of intersection of two curves

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two functions monotonically increasing or decreasing in $[0, \infty]$. Suppose the point of intersection of these functions is $(a,b)$. Is there a method to find the point of intersection of $f(x)$ and $g(x-h) ; h \geq 0; h$ is an integer.

Comment: It looks like if you "replace" $x$ by $x-h$, that you are performing a horizontal shift. Of course, the point of intersection is then changing too, but one of the coordinates stays the same. Which one? Perhaps you can use invariant coordinate to find the other...

Comment: @imranfat - No, both the coordinates change. Consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$ and, $h=1$. In this case $(a,b)$ is $(1,1)$ and, point of intersection of $f(x)$ and $g(x-1)$ is (3.1479,9.9)

Comment: You got me on that one. Never thought (ahum) that $f(x)$ could also be curvey...This question is harder than I thought, I admit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you know about the functions? If they are completely generic, there is no "trick": you just have to solve
$$g(x-h)-f(x) =0 $$
for $x$, which possibly can only be done approximately (using e.g. Newton's method) if there is no nice formula for the two functions.

Notice that monotonicity of the functions doesn't help that much, since they can still dovetail with multiple points of intersection: consider for instance $$f(x) = x + \sin x, \quad g(x) = x.$$